# How to restart scylla db cluster without any data loss

Tags: scylla

I want to restart my Scylla db cluster. But I don't want to lose any data.

Do I lose any data if I restart one after other node?

Answer (score 3):

If "restarting a node" just involves restarting Scylla or rebooting the kernel on which it runs, then you're safe: Scylla is a distributed database, and is designed to support durability and availability even when nodes temporarily disappear from the network. When a node is temporarily down, all its data is still available for reads (from two other replicas), and also writes continue to work normally and will be eventually replicated to the down node when it finally comes up (using the "hinted handoff" and/or "repair" mechanisms).

However, if by "restarting a node" you mean something more destructive - replacing it with a brand-new node with empty storage, as in some cloud setups where nodes have transient storage. In that case you have to be more careful: If the node's data is lost, we still have two more replicas and the database continues to be available, but you should tell the cluster to "stream" the data which the node lost back to the node - before continuing to do this destructive restart to additional nodes. If you have RF=3 and destroy three nodes at the same time, you will surely lose data.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not loose data if you are doing a rolling restart.
Scylla keeps the data replicated across multiple nodes (usually 3 or more)

Depending on your Replication Factor (RF) and Consistency Level (CL) you might see read or write operations failed during the restart. See interactive calc here https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/consistency/#consistency-level-calculator